# How to Retrieve Subscriber email address?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, verify

I have created a Wordpress landing page, actually i wanna retrieve Subscribers email address, what should i do, i'm beginner in PHP/Wordpress  .

Something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can use contactform7, gravityform and many other subscribe plugins

Comment: is it possible without using any plugin ? bcoz i wanna learn how to Handle Those Things  .

Comment: There are so many ways and of-course time consuming as well like you need to create custom post type then stored data in that and also create the page at admin side which displayed all this listing,
you can also use custom table for the same.

Comment: thanks for valuable comment !

Comment: Let me add as a answer so you can like and give up vote :)

Comment: of course brother , i did it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways to achieve this.

1. Use contactform7, gravityform, ninjaform or any other form related plugins
2. Create custom post type and save form data in that post type and displayed all saved data at admin side.
3. Create custom database table and save form data in that table and retrieve those data at admin side.